# How to make a pygame sound only play once, then stop until the requirements are met again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a sprite collecting game where I collect sprites and the score counts up. If I bump into the wall, it will execute a sound of hitting the wall. When I hit the wall, I only want the sound to play one time, and then refrain from playing til the requirements are met again. Here is my code with sound collision with the wall.

```
def wallCollide():
    if player.rect.x == 1 and player.rect.y < 479:
        bumpWall.play()
    if player.rect.y == 1 and player.rect.x < 479:
        bumpWall.play()
    if player.rect.x == 478 and player.rect.y < 479:
        bumpWall.play()
    if player.rect.y == 478 and player.rect.x < 479:
        bumpWall.play()
```

Comment: mayb you should set `play = False` before `if`, and `play = True` inside `if` and then use it to play sond after all checking all collisions. OR maybe you should use [player.rect.coliderect(list_with_many_rect)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to check all in one line.

Comment: OR maybe you should move player little back so it will not touch wall after collision. If you don't move back then it collide all time.

Comment: OR maybe you should check also speed. If you touch wall but you doesn't move (speed is `0`) then don't play sound.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack would be to move (teleport) the player 2~5 pixels away from the the wall at the same frame the player has hit the wall.

But in case you want player to stay inside the wall and/or slide near the wall then you need more robust solution. Using state machine:

```py
PL_STATE_WITHIN_BOUNDS = 1
PL_STATE_JUST_HIT_THE_WALL = 2
PL_STATE_COLLIDING_WITH_THE_WALL = 3

def calc_next_player_state(player, pl_state):
    # Convert your `wallCollide` to return bool:
    # - False when within bounds
    # - True when colliding with the wall
    if is_colliding_with_the_wall(player):
        if pl_state == PL_STATE_WITHIN_BOUNDS:
            return PL_STATE_JUST_HIT_THE_WALL
        else:
            return PL_STATE_COLLIDING_WITH_THE_WALL
    else:
        return PL_STATE_WITHIN_BOUNDS

pl_state = PL_STATE_WITHIN_BOUNDS

while True:  # Game's main loop
    # ...

    pl_state = calc_next_player_state(player, pl_state)
    if pl_state == PL_STATE_JUST_HIT_THE_WALL:
        bump_wall.play()

    # ...
```